# C# sorts range of elements in descending order

Tags: c#, sorting

I have [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. How can I sort the elements from 3 -> 5 in descending order? Expected: [1, 2, 5, 4, 3]

Comment: Before submitting a question here, you should always try pasting the title of your question into Google.

Comment: and you should always post sample of existing code as it pertains to your problem and or issue. this is a very poor / low level question , please edit it and read how to ask a question while you have all this down time

Comment: Maybe? ``list.Take(2).OrderBy().Union(list.Skip(2).OrderByDescending());``

Comment: You put `C#` in your questions twice but didn't include any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `System.Linq`, you can `Take` the first two items, then `Concat` that with the rest of the list after calling `Reverse`:

```
var items = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var sorted = items.Take(2).Concat(items.Skip(2).Reverse());
```

---

**Update:** You can take this logic and create a more generic implementation, such as:

```
private static int[] SortRangeReverse(int[] input, int startRange, int endRange)
{
    // Argument validation - decide what you want to do if the args aren't what you expect
    if (input == null || input.Length < 2) return input;
    if (endRange <= startRange) return input;
    if (startRange < 0) startRange = 0;

    // The actual "meat" of the original answer in a more generic form:
    return
        input.Take(startRange)
            .Concat(input.Skip(startRange).Take(endRange + 1 - startRange).Reverse()
            .Concat(input.Skip(endRange + 1)))
            .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: If you're just going to hard code an answer, and write a solution that won't work for any other input values, why not just write out `var sorted = new[]{1, 2, 5,4,3};` and be done with it.

Comment: @Servy Oh, that would have been better! ;)

Comment: @Servy its kind of impossible to come up with something else with only pseudo data provided from OP, there isnt really anthing than the fixed 2 we can figure out or can you provide a more "dynamic" approach?

Comment: @RandRandom If you don't have enough information to answer the question (which I agree, doesn't provide enough information to actually provide an answer) then *don't post an answer to the question*.  If you feel the question doesn't provide enough information to be answered, vote to close for the appropriate reason.

Comment: @Servy well at least someone is happy with that answer, should I be scared now that OP's bio says "Software Engineer at Microsoft" :)

Comment: I posted a more generic solution based on the original answer

Comment: @RandRandom That they're happy with a hard coded answer doesn't mean it's actually a working answer.  That you know it's not actually a good answer to the question makes it *worse*, it means you've now tricked someone into *thinking* that they've actually solved their problem when they haven't actually solved it, which is worse than knowing that they don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I don't see why this particular "hard coded" answer is such a problem. I solved the specific example in the question and provided a basis for which the OP can modify it to work for his or her specific needs. Basically introduces `Take`, `Skip`, `Reverse`, and `Concat` (along with method chaining, which isn't relevant). But since the specifics of what he wants are not clear, an exact generic solution seemed like guesswork. But after these comments, I added one anyway.

Comment: @KevinAvignon Can you clarify what manipulations are you talking about, and why `OrderByDescending` instead of `Reverse`?

Answer (score 0):

Sort in forward order then call [reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx) for the last few elements.

Answer (score 0):

Run on the Array Until you get an object bigger then 2.
flip that object with the last object.

let see if you figure out the rest